# Mocking Using JMockit

Tags: java, groovy, junit, grails-2.0, jmockit

I need to mock a method in a java class that is like this:

```
public class Helper{

    public static message(final String serviceUrl){   

        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
        HttpMethod httpmethod = new HttpMethod();

        // the below is the line that iam trying to mock
        String code = httpClient.executeMethod(method);

    }
}
```

I have tried to write the junit in groovy, but not able to do so as grrovy meta-proggraming techniques do not apply for java classes. On my research, i have found out that JMockit is a good framework that can also mock objects that are created using new constructor.

Can somebody show me how to write the unittest for the above class either in java or in groovy.

Advanced Thanks

this is the test case that i have tried so far using jmockit, but does not work..

```
void testSend(){

    def serviceUrl = properties.getProperty("PROP").toString()

    new Expectations(){
        {
            HttpClient httpClient=new HttpClient();
            httpClient.executeMethod(); returns null;
        }        
    };
    def responseXml = Helper.sendMessage(requestXml.toString(), serviceUrl)            
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything with JMockit yet? I know your last, essentially-identical question suggested JMockit, there's also Mockito and EasyMock. Examples abound--what have you tried?

Comment: I have added an edit to my question showing the test that I have written....As the mock object that iam looking into is httpClient, do you think is it better if I go with java or with groovy for writting test case

Answer (score 2):

The java version of your test case would look like:

```
@Test
public void testSend() throws IOException {

    final String serviceUrl = "http://google.com/";

    new Expectations(){
        // these bits are important as they tell Jmockit what classes to mock
        @Mocked HttpClient client ;
        @Mocked GetMethod method;

        {
            HttpClient httpClient= new HttpClient() ;
            HttpMethod method = new GetMethod(withEqual(serviceUrl));
            try {
                httpClient.executeMethod(method);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // not going to happen
            }
            result = 200;
        }
    };
    // run the test and assert something
    Assert.assertEquals(200, Helper.message(serviceUrl));
}
```

This is available on [github.com](https://github.com/gid79/q12271389-jmock-example), note I used httpClient 3.1 to implement your message method, I'm guessing that isn't quite right, but should be enough to answer the question.

If you can prep a simple grails project with your test case in I'm sure I can figure out what the issue is.

**Update**: I've been playing with a toy grails project locally and haven't managed to configure jmockit correctly. The key thing with jmockit is to ensure it is before junit on the classpath, but since junit is shipped in grails I can't find away to get jmockit in the right place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How Do I start using Jmockit in my grails project. I checked for Jmockit plugin in grails plugin manager, but did not find any.

Comment: this is why a simple grails project setup in the same way as you have done in your project would be most useful. One of the tricky things with JMockit is the classpath setup, specifically it needs to be on the CP before JUnit.

Answer (score 2):

With jmockit you can also mock instance creation.  I prefer slightly different technique:

```
@Test    
public void testFoo(@Mocked final HttpClient client) {
       new Expectations() {{
              // expect instance creation and return mocked one
              new HttpClient(... );  returns(client)

              // expect invocations on this mocked instance
             client.invokeSomeMethid(); returns(something)
       }};


        helper.message(serviceUrl)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How Do I start using Jmockit in my grails project. I checked for Jmockit plugin in grails plugin manager, but did not find any.

Comment: no idea how grails plugin architecture works.   but provided jmockit is on classpath before test harness it can instrument annotated classes.   jmockit dedicated lists maz be better information source

Answer (score 0):

thanks for raising the question, with Spring-web-3.2.2 (which uses httpclient-4.0.1), my code looks like this:

```
    new NonStrictExpectations(){
        @Mocked(methods={"executeMethod"})
        ClientHttpRequest mocked_req;
        @Mocked(methods={"getBody"})
        ClientHttpResponse mocked_res;
        {
            byte[] buf  = (
            "<example_xml><person><name>Johnson</name><age>20</age></person></example_xml>" 
            ).getBytes();

            mocked_req.execute();
            mocked_res.getBody(); returns(new ByteArrayInputStream(buf));

        }
    };


    RestTemplate mytemplate = new RestTemplate();
    obj =         mytemplate.getForObject(.....);
    assertEquals("returned and parsed obj should be equal to this one", expectedObj, obj);
```